# How can I write to certain sections of a file only with filestream?

Tags: c#, filestream

I don't want to write an entire file if only a small portion of that file has changed, is there a way to modify only a section of a file without opening/rewriting the entire file? The file will aways be 32mb and no inserts/deletes, just overwriting only.

For example, here I have a 32mb file with only about 1mb of data that changed, it seems inefficient to load the entire file into memory and resave. In c# is there a way to open/read only 1 section of a file and modify that section only?

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream ("testfile.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)) 
{
    fileStream.SetLength (totalDummyFileSize); //create 32mb file
    //just dummy data for testing
    fileStream.Write(new byte[lookupTableSizeInBytes],0,lookupTableSizeInBytes); 
    fileStream.Seek (datatToWriteLocation, SeekOrigin.Current);
    fileStream.Write(dataToWrite, 0, dataToWrite.Length);
}
```

Then trying to read:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream ("testfile.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)) 
{
        fileStream.Seek(dataLocation,SeekOrigin.Current);
        fileStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

But the data isn't there when I try to read at the location of my last write.

Edit: The file size will never change, it will always be 32mb so there is no inserting/deleting, just overwriting.

Comment: If your modification is a 1-for-1 byte change then you can simply overwrite the existing data. However, if you need to delete or insert bytes you're left with a lot more work.

Comment: just seek to the offset you want and write what you want, but as other have pointed out you can only do a 1 for 1 byte replacement

Comment: That is all I want to do is 1 for 1 byte replace, ty.

Comment: 32 MB isn't much, and you don't need to read the entire file into memory. Reading and rewriting the entire file block by block (ex. 64 KB/block) will do just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify a section of a file that is completely within the file by overwriting bytes one by one you can use this code:

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(path)) {
  fileStream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

This will write `bytes` at `offset` in the file at `path`.

Comment: Thanks, using this worked. Is there any performance difference between this vs 'using new FileStream'? I assume they would be same in performance given they are both part of FileStream, no?

Comment: @Euthyphro: No, there is no performance difference. The `File` class has some static methods to make opening and creation of files simple.